# How to remove/disable the menu item from RulerContextMenu of Editor?

Tags: java, eclipse, editor, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

I want to disable/remove the menu item from vertical rulerContext Menu.
I did following Steps:

1 I have registered `RulerContextListener` with `CEditor`. So that whenever user right click on vertical margin of Editor then  control come to there.

```
CEditor editor = (CEditor) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
                          .getActivePage().getActiveEditor();

if(editor != null)
   editor.addRulerContextMenuListener(new RulerMenuListener());
```

2 In `MenuAboutShow()` I wrote following code but first time menuItem is listing as empty.

3 On second time onward, It is displaying Menu Item as 
`Toggle Brea&kpoint`, `&Add Breakpoint...Ctrl+Double Click`, `Add &Dynamic Printf...`, `&Enable Breakpoint  Shift+Double Click` etc..
I disabled the "**Add &Dynamic Printf**" menu.

```
CEditor editor = (CEditor)PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor();
IVerticalRulerInfo rulerInfo = (IVerticalRulerInfo)editor.getAdapter(IVerticalRulerInfo.class);
Menu RulerMenu = rulerInfo.getControl().getMenu();
MenuItem[] RulerMenuItem=  RulerMenu.getItems();
for(int i=0;i<RulerMenuItem.length;i++) {
   System.out.println(RulerMenuItem[i].getText()+"\n");
   if(RulerMenuItem[i].getText().contains("Add &Dynamic Printf")) {
      if(RulerMenuItem[i].isEnabled()){
          RulerMenuItem[i].setEnabled(false);
      }
   }
}
rulerInfo.getControl().setMenu(RulerMenu);
```

4 but it is not disabling . Still this menu item is displayed as enabled.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZMZN.png)
Can Someone please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: You can and should only remove or disable something if you added it. Otherwise, this is a contribution from another plug-in, and a bug for its authors to fix.

Comment: `CEditor` is an **internal** class. You are breaking the [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html) by using it.